# How to unit test a non-module with jasmine-node? (related to turning off node integration in Electron)

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, jasmine, electron, jasmine-node

I have a bit of a dilemma.

I turned on `contextIsolation` and turned off `nodeIntegration` for my `BrowserWindow` and loaded a local html page. (as is recommended by Electron).

This local html page requires a node module, which causes a crash, because Electron can't load a node module in the window since node is disabled:

main.ts:

```
import { app, BrowserWindow } from "electron";
import * as path from "path";

function createWindow() {
  const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: false,
      contextIsolation: true,
      preload: path.join(__dirname, "preload.js"),
    },
  });

  mainWindow.loadFile(path.join(__dirname, "../index.html"));
  mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();
}

(async () => {
  await app.whenReady();
  createWindow();
})();

app.on("window-all-closed", () => {
  if (process.platform !== "darwin") {
    app.quit();
  }
});
```

index.html:

```
<body>
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>
  <script src="./renderer.js"></script>
</body>
```

renderer.js:

```
export interface A { }
```

> Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined
> at renderer.js:2

The specific line that crashes is this:

`Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });` which exists because of the `export` statement.

I can remove the export in this case (and just redefine the interface in the other module that needs it), but then I can't unit test my script.

I'm currently using [`jasmine-node`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jasmine-node) for unit testing and I've been requiring the module that I want to test at the top:

```
import * as Renderer from "./renderer"
```

This errors out in VSCode with something about how `Renderer` isn't a module.

It seems that requiring works (I guess Node can `require` non-modules?), but this causes the IIFE to run before my spies are set up.

If `Renderer` were a module, I would do:

```
<script>
   require("renderer.js").main();
</script>
```

And then my unit tests would set up the spies on the module before calling the main method. But since I can't `require` in my index.html since I've disabled Node, I have to load the script inline, and so I need some kind of IIFE to replace the main method:

```
(async () => {
   await doSomething();
})();
```

How can I unit test this non-module then with Jasmine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution ended up being hacky.

First, I had to make my non-module a module, so that I could import it in my specs.

I exported my interface and added a main method:

```
export interface A { }
export async function main(): Promise<void> {
    await doSomething();
}
```

To avoid the crash I was getting before when I was loading a script with Node disabled, I added this hack to my html page:

```
<script>var exports = {};</script> // mutes the "exports not defined" error
<script src="./renderer.js"></script>
```

And then I made my IIFE call my main method if jasmine isn't running.

```
(async () => {
    if (!window.jasmine) {
        main();
    }
})();
```

My unit tests meanwhile set up the spies and call the exported main method.